# How to use a type guard when the type is declared in an imported module (jsonrpc-lite)?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to setup a type guard, so that the subsequent code knows that an object is of certain type and can infer its properties. However, I don't know how to reference the type I want to check for. The type is in an npm module (jsonrpc-lite).

How do I reference the type in my type guard?

I'm using typescript version 3.2. Please note: I'm new to typescript!

First try (without type guard):

```js
// somefile.ts
import * as jsonrpc from "jsonrpc-lite"

export const foo = (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) => {

  const payload = jsonrpc.parseObject(req.body).payload // fine!
  console.log(payload.id) // Fails!
  // Gives me: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'SuccessObject | NotificationObject | RequestObject | ErrorObject | JsonRpcError'

// ...
}
```

Second attempt:

I know that the `id` property is available on the payload if the type is `RequestObject`, so I figured I could augment the code with a type guard.

I assume the `RequestObject` type must be visible to the type system in the first place since it says that `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'SuccessObject | NotificationObject | RequestObject | ErrorObject | JsonRpcError'`

However, I don't know how to reference the jsonrpc-lite `RequestObject` in my type guard -- see the question marks below.

```js
  // My type guard
  // The problem is that I don't know what to write in place of ??????. 
  // I want to reference jsonrpc-lite's RequestObject type:
  const isRequestObj = (payload: any): payload is ?????? => {
    return true
  }
```

This is the d.ts file for jsonrpc-lite: https://github.com/teambition/jsonrpc-lite/blob/master/jsonrpc.d.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the best solution would be to convince the developers of the package to export all the important types. Because any updates to the package may cause the other solutions to stop working.

The next-to-optimal solution would be to do structural type matching and differentiate only those properties that you really use:

```js
const hasId = (payload: any): payload is { id: string } =>
  typeof payload === 'object' && typeof payload.id === 'string';
```

But since the question was really about retrieving the type, here's how to do it, even thought it might stop working with an update:

```js
type payload = ReturnType<typeof jsonrpc.parseObject>["payload"];

type matchRequest<T> = T extends {
    id: string | number;
    method: string;
    params?: object;
} ? T : never;

type RequestObject = matchRequest<payload>;
```

Comment: Thanks! I've raised the issue on jsonrpc-lites GitHub repo: https://github.com/teambition/jsonrpc-lite/issues/11#issuecomment-482943158. Hopefully It will be picked up by the package devs.

Comment: @andy-bc  `dummyFunction` is unnecessary, you can use the built-in type `ReturnType`. Its definition goes: `type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;`.